# Incremental Backups In SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup

I am very much aware that native SQL server backups has full/differential/log backup strategies which are not really an incremental backups and would like to know if there are any 3rd party tools to implement an incremental backup strategy ?

Comment: That's right. I very much understand that but for log backups you need to have the DB in full recovery where as for differential can be taken for a DB under simple with a base initially .So my question is with Diff backups which is not a true incremental backup and if there is a way where we can have simple recovery and take a true incremental backups ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Transaction log backups are incremental, that is, they only store incremental changes since the previous transaction log backup.

You are confusing the differential log backup with "backups are not incremental", because differential backups only keep a record of the changes since the last *full* backup.

(Differential backups work in all recovery models, namely Simple, Bulk-Logged, and Full.)

If you want incremental backups, take transaction log backups regularly.

Comment: That's right. I very much understand that but for log backups you need to have the DB in full recovery where as for differential can be taken for a DB under simple with a base initially .So my question is with Diff backups which is not a true incremental backup and if there is a way where we can have simple recovery and take a true incremental backups ? Hope this is not confusing you.

Comment: Differential backups work in the Simple, Bulk-Logged and Full Recovery model. I'm not quite sure *what* it is you're asking. What exactly is the aversion to transaction log backups if the requirement is for incremental backups?